# iMovie 10.0.9 Won't load video

Tags: video, imovie

I have a camcorder hooked up to my iMac running iMovie 10.0.9. When I try to import the video, I get question marks, and then the HDD Camera clicks off the menu. How can I get the video into iMovie to edit?

Answer (score 1):

Try using Mac's Image Capture (in Applications folder). Then import video to iPhoto instead of iMovie. Then iMovie will automatically import your video from iPhoto.

It's the long way around, I know, but it worked for me.

- Daniel

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible if your trying to convert another video that's already on your computer. This is unless you get Adobe Media Encoder which costs a ton of money.